# How do you install all missing packages with NeoBundle?

Tags: vim

If I've just added a package to my vimrc file, how do I get NeoBundle to install it without restarting vim? `NeoBundleInstall` doesn't work. It tells me all packages are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just changed the plugins in your `.vimrc` file, your changes are not loaded into the vim environment yet. You need to [reload the `.vimrc` file](https://superuser.com/questions/132029/how-do-you-reload-your-vimrc-file-without-restarting-vim).

```
:so $MYVIMRC
:NeoBundleInstall
```

Comment: I also found that if I `:source ~/.vimrc` it will ask me to install the missing bundles.